# Ionic 4: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.). Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

**Html Code**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title> Add Form </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Company Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input
          formControlName="company"
          autocapitalize
          inputmode="text"
        ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.company">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="company.hasError(error.type)&&(company.dirty || company.touched)" >
          <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Meet With</ion-label>
        <ion-input
          formControlName="meet_With"

          inputmode="text"
        ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.meet_With">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="meet_With.hasError(error.type)&&(meet_With.dirty || meet_With.touched)"
        >
          <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Email ID</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="email" inputmode="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.email">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="email.hasError(error.type)&&(email.dirty || email.touched)"
        >
          <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
        </ng-container>
      </div>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Purpose</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="purpose" inputmode="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.purpose">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="purpose.hasError(error.type)&&(purpose.dirty || purpose.touched)"
        >
          <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Comment</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="comments" inputmode="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Date and Time</ion-label>
        <ion-input
          formControlName="date_and_time"
          autocapitalize="date & time"
        ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="ion-padding">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime
            displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY  HH : mm "
            [min]="minDate"
            [max]="maxDate"
          ></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label positon="floating">Location </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="location" autocapitalize="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div id="poidiv">
        <div *ngIf="pois" class="ion-padding  ">
          <ion-list *ngFor="let poi of pois">
            <ion-item
              ><img src="{'{poi.icon}'}" style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' src = "{'{poi.icon}'} "/>{
              {poi.name}} </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    <ion-button
      [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid"
      type="submit"
      expand="block">
      Save
      <ion-icon slot="end" company="create"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
</form>
  </ion-content>
```

**Error**

> {     "resource": "/Users/atripathi/apps/src/app/home/home.page.html",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#0",    "severity": 8,
> "message": "Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'.",     "source": "ng",
> "startLineNumber": 104,     "startColumn": 20,  "endLineNumber": 104,
> "endColumn": 20 }
>
> {     "resource": "/Users/atripathi/apps/src/app/home/home.page.html",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#0",    "severity": 8,
> "message": "Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped
> "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)",   "source":
> "ng",     "startLineNumber": 104,     "startColumn": 20,  "endLineNumber":
> 104,  "endColumn": 20 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <ion-item>
      <img src="{{poi.icon}}" style='width: 20px; height: 20px;'/>{{poi.name}} 
    </ion-item>
```

*poi.icon* should be an url.